# APTANA: Ignore .project file when uploading?

Tags: eclipse, svn, aptana, aptana3

I'm new to Aptana and I noticed that when uploading via FTP or checking in a project through SVN, it also uploads / checks in the .project file. I did hide this and other hidden files in the Project and App Explorers but for some reason the .project file still uploads when deploying a whole project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you use command line SVN client (like CollabNet Subversion on Windows), go to your project folder which contains .project and .classpath file (we usually ignore both with some other IDE generated folders/files), this is the command to add a specific file to SVN ignore list:

```
> svn propset svn:ignore -F .project
```

If you use GUI SVN client (like TortoiseSVN on Windows), ignore function is usually integrated into Right-Click Menu, right click the file you want to ignored then choose TortoiseSVN -- Delete and add to ignore list).

Check out the ignore section in SVN user giude [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3).